# create bookmarks for separate pdf files using the filename

Tags: python, pypdf

Hi I am trying to merge multiple pdfs with the filename of each pdf as the bookmark I intent to do this by merging the pdfs once the bookmark has been created on each pdf individually, I have managed to merge all pdfs and I have managed to make a bookmark for an individual pdf using the pdfs filename however I have not been able to add a bookmark to multiple pdfs at once. please could anyone advise on how this could be done? below is the code for making the bookmark the pdf name:

```py
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

directory = r'C:filepath\\21-07398.pdf'
source_dir = os.getcwd()

pathname, extension = os.path.splitext(directory)
filename = pathname.split('\\')


filename1 = filename[-1]
print(filename1)
reader = PdfFileReader(directory) 
writer = PdfFileWriter()  

n = reader.getNumPages()
for i in range(n):
    writer.addPage(reader.getPage(i))  
writer.addBookmark(filename1, 0, parent=None)

with open("./result/result.pdf", "wb") as gg:  
    writer.write(gg)
```

Comment: Please don't use deprecated classes. Run your code with python -Wall script.py to see the warnings

Answer (score 2):

- https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/merging-pdfs.html
- https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/PdfMerger.html?highlight=bookmark#PyPDF2.PdfMerger.add_bookmark

You can merge the pdfs and create the bookmarks as you go.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger
merger = PdfMerger()
//files is supposed to be a list of your filenames.
for file in files:
  merger.append(file)
for i in range(len(files)):
  merger.add_outline_item(title=str(files[i],pagenum=i))
merger.write(<outputFileName>)
merger.close()
```

Comment: thanks for that I made some changes as the 'add_outline_item' wasnt working for me issue is this adds a book mark for each new page and as my pdfs  have multiple pages this doesnt solve the issue I need a way to position the bookmarks on the start of each different pdf